# IIS Manager - replace URL containing folder structure with only Website URL

Tags: web, url, iis, url-rewriting

we are using a website which is managed via IIS Manager.
A web tool is currently accessed via the full URL containing the folder structure. So if someone does trial and error with different paths in the Search bar he could reach unwanted documents hidden under the folder structure.

The target is to hide the full folder path and only show the webtool adress as shown in the example:
https://webtool.test.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/index.html
Target:
https://webtool.test.com/

and if I type:
webtool.test.com
the index.html should be shown but without the full URl showing up in the browser bar.

What i have tried so far is basicaly every instruction on the web that i found regarding writing rewrite and redirect rules in the IIS Manager. Nothing seems to change anything and if it does i get a 500 Error.

Since I have basically never before done something like that, I am most likely doing something wrong. So I am asking here for help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you please describe your issue in more detail. in my opinion it is not possible all the folder path from the url. you have to specify the path you want to rewrite or hide. 60

Answer (score 0):

To achieve URL masking and redirection in IIS Manager, follow these steps:

1. Install the URL Rewrite module in IIS Manager.
2. Open IIS Manager on the server where your website is hosted.
3. Select Your Website in the Connections pane.
4. Click on "URL Rewrite" in the center pane.
5. Add a New Rule in the URL Rewrite window.
6. Configure the Rule details, such as name, match URL, conditions, action type, and server variables.
7. Apply and save the rule.
8. Test the configuration by accessing your website with the desired URL.
9. Redirect Non-WWW to WWW by adding another rule.
10. Apply and save the new rule.
11. Test the redirect to ensure it works as expected.

Back up your IIS configuration before making changes.